# Getting instruction given address pointed by the instruction pointer

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I am working on this code where, I need to get the instructions executed by a program, given the instruction pointers. Assume for now that I have a mechanism that provides me addresses of the instructions, would it be possible to get the opcode from this (on an IA32 instruction set) ?

Comment: Get the processor docs and look up in the opcode tables. Or find an open source disassembler.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan well, the problem is, given the instruction pointer, I am not sure how to get the opcode since the number of bytes for each opcode might vary (correct me on this if am wrong, am not too sure on this) ..

Comment: It's all explained in the processor docs. Each instruction is described very fully, including the instruction size. Easier by far to use ready made disasm code.

Comment: @sanz: It is a big task to do that. As you've noticed on instruction length on IA32 varies from instruction to instruction. In addition there are x86_64 architectures with some new instructions, some removed etc. You god SSEs, 3Dnows, FPU instructions. Better use existing disassemblers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an in memory disassembler, such as [BeaEngine](http://www.beaengine.org/) or [DiStorm](http://ragestorm.net/distorm/), these can be passed a memory address to read from, just make sure the address is readable. If you know the length in bytes of the function, its a little better to use the Run-Length-Dissassemblers also provided on those sites.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for hardware supported help, that's not how it works. This needs to be done in software. Your code needs a table of opcodes and instructions and just has to perform a lookup.

What you describe is known as disassembly. There are many open source disassemblers and if you could use one of those it would make your task very simple. Look here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Disassemblers_and_Decompilers